# Column Pandas Dataframe not transposing

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I start off by importing a giant CSV that was originally an .xls and then start breaking up the imported data into their specific columns.

```
data = pd.read_csv('csv_acrylic_arranged.csv')

X_wavelength = data.iloc[:, 0]

y_2287 = data.iloc[:, 8] 
y_2092 = data.iloc[:, 10]

y_2208 = data.iloc[:, 19]
y_373 = data.iloc[:, 21]

y_2051 = data.iloc[:, 30]
y_9092 = data.iloc[:, 32]

y_2146 = data.iloc[:, 41]
y_2424 = data.iloc[:, 43]
```

And it goes on until I get to the like 170th column - I only realized after I could have just done a for loop :(

But when I want to reformat the data into a new CSV. So since all these `y_VALUE` are in columns, I would need to transpose and concat. When I check the concat its the same values as before!
[image]

Comment: What is the question?  Without a [mcve] it will be hard for anyone to spot your problem.  Sometimes creating a [mcve] for your question will help you figure out what is going wrong.  Please don't post images of code or data.

Comment: You tried to transpose a `Series`, which is just itself (1 dim). If you do `df["col"] = y_xxxx` you'll create a brand new column with y_xxx values. Now you'll have a 2-dim `df`that can be transposed

Comment: @RafaelC idk, I'm getting a df is not defined error?  I can't find any examples of Series.to_frame() either so I don't know how that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was super dumb you can just go

```
pd.DataFrame(data = y_XXXX) = r_XXXX
r_XXXX = r_XXXX.T
```

Thanks everyone.